# Cannot insert zero in to MySQL INT NULL

Tags: mysql

I have a query that save zero in one of the MySQL column.

Column was set to be `NULL` = no and `Default` = none. But my query wasnt working when i had that structurer when I save 0. So i change the value to null. But when saving 0 (zero) in database its still getting saved NULL.

When i had the column set to be `NULL` = no and `Default` it was working fine on my localhost but in my hosting query wasn't getting inserted. that is why i change it to null.

MySQL version 5.6.30

Query

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO categories(cname, cat_description, cat_ parent) VALUES ('$cname', '$description', '0')");
```

Comment: And where is the query you tried?

Comment: I appreciate that English might not be your first language, but it's very difficult to understand exactly what you're saying.  Copy and pasting your query & results, and showing what results you expected instead, would really help to clarify what's going on.

Comment: "*When i had the column set to be NULL = no and Default*": and default... default what?

Comment: Yes english is not my 1st language.Its a simple insert code.issue is that i cannot save 0 in the database. it always save NULL and if i make the column not null insert query wont work. This is happing only with my new hosting provider.

Comment: We need at least the schema of you table (`DESC tablename` or `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`) and the insert query you run.

Comment: query added. This is only happening in hostgator vps.

Comment: I'm not running after 2 rep, but not accepting my retag and retagging yourself later is actually not appropriate behaviour on community site like SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are actually trying to insert a `string` in an `integer` column. MySQL does not accept this. And it shouldn't.

Insert an integer:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO categories(cname, cat_description, cat_ parent) VALUES ('$cname', '$description', 0)");
```

Just remove the quotes around `0`.

Comment: With default configuration MySQL will cast the string to int ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aaf44/1)).

Comment: But there is no way to know if her hosting provider uses a default configuration (they should not, actually).

Comment: thank you it worls great. so normally if dont use patent in other hosting providers its automatically saving 0. so is this happing in hostgator because the strict mysql is turned on?

Comment: That's what a strict configuration is for.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.